# Cordova app - scrolling issue on android 5 Lollipop

Tags: css, cordova, android-5.0-lollipop, ratchet-2

I have developed a cordova app and I'm testing it on my phone with Android 5.0 Lollipop.
I found a problem with Android hardware acceleration, if it's enabled there are CSS rendering issues as you can see in [this](https://vid.me/gb0n) video.

Look at the white spaces that show up during scrolling and also you can see that every list item (`<li>`) is blurry during scroll and when I stop scrolling item shows normally.

As far as I was using previous Android 4.x versions there was no such problem. 
If I disable HW acceleration I have there is no issue anymore, but performance are bad because I used some CSS tricks elsewhere to get better performance in CSS.

Here is some of my code related to the video:

html: (using handlebars)

```
<div id='view'>
<ul>
    {{#each []}}
        <li> 
                {{@index}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
li {
    background-color: grey;

    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(243, 255, 226);
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#view {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
     perspective: 1000;
     backface-visibility: hidden;

     -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

I'm also using ratchet to get some basic CSS.

Anyone with same issue? 
Do you think it's a cordova or Android Lollipop WebView bug?

Any chance to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: is the issue fixed. I'm facing too.

Comment: Did anybody got any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try compiling with Crosswalk? Hope it resolves it.

Comment: Try switching to Native Scrolling and JQScroll, update to latest appframework ui and css from their git.